# Find appropriate matrix which Scales the square S to 4 times its area using python

Tags: python, matrix, area, algebra, square

Let S be the square with vertices (-1,1), (1,1), (1,-1), (-1,-1). Let the matrix representation of the vertices be:

[image]

Each column of the matrix represents a vertex of the square.

Find an appropriate matrix which scales the square S to 4 times its area. Let the resultant square be S_scaled and return using python.

I tried finding determinant to find its area but it doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

```
import math
import numpy as np

S = np.matrix([[-1, 1, 1, -1],[1, 1, -1, -1]])

# https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transformation_matrix
# square centered at (0,0) -> scaling area by 4 == scale vectors of S by sqrt(4)
scale = math.sqrt(4)
T = np.matrix([[scale, 0], [0, scale]])

S_scaled = np.matmul(T, S)
print(S_scaled)

# ...or simply: multiply S by sqrt(4)
S_scaled = np.multiply(S, scale)
print(S_scaled)
```

output:

```
[[-2.  2.  2. -2.]
 [ 2.  2. -2. -2.]]
```